# Why doesn't next in asyncHandler stop execution?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, asynchronous

I have a NodeJS typescript project in which I have the following endpoint which has an async function:

```js
router.post('/login', login)
```

with the following function

```js
const login = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const credentials: Credentials = req.body as Credentials
  await UserService.findUserByEmail(credentials.email).then(user => {
    if (user != null) {
      if (user.password === credentials.password) {
        res.status(200).send('Token will be here in future')
        next()
      }
    }
    res.status(401).send('Email or password is wrong')
    next()
  })
})
```

However, even though when I call this endpoint and get an HTTP 200 response, in the terminal i get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

After researching, apparently what's happening is that the `res.send(400)` line is being called even after the `res.status(200)` line was run and the `next()` line after it as well. I **know** I can fix this error by putting an `if-else` block, but I want to understand, why even though I've called next, the function keeps executing. I've noticed I can use a `return` and that would stop it, but it seems a bit non-clean.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: why do u call next() ? once u send the status it's end of the call. Also, res.status() does not equals to return. If you want to end the call u need to return. If there's no return, next line will be called.

Comment: If you send a response, do NOT call `next()` because that will continue routing onto something else that will then send ANOTHER response and you will get the error you get.  If you are sending a response,  you want to STOP further routing by NOT calling `next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` calls the next middleware, but does not stop the execution of the function. A clean way of writing this would be `return next()`. Although in this case, you've already sent the result so there's no need to call next in the first place.